# android Database access not working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

what i am trying do is create a table then insert some values into it then and select. 
The problem i am facing is the app is unfortunately stopping.I don't know what is the problem.

My code is:
This class calls the database handler

```
public class SaveEvents extends Activity {
private static final String DB_NAME = "EventDB";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);
    Bundle extras=getIntent().getExtras();
    String event=extras.getString("event");
    String date=extras.getString("date");
    String college=extras.getString("college");

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    db.insert_data(event,date,college);
    String c=db.select_data();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "EventName: "+c+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Database Handler

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EventDB";
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "eventlist";


public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // Category table create query
    String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE;
    CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE eventlist(eventname varchar(100),eventdate varchar(100),college varchar(100));";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
void insert_data(String eventname,String date,String college)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("eventname", eventname);
    values.put("eventdate",date);
    values.put("college",college);
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    db.close();
}
public String select_data()
   {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT eventname FROM eventlist where eventname='techcontest'";
    String c=null;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    c=cursor.getString(0);
    return c;
}
}
```

My logcat shows

```
03-16 20:00:19.116    8378-8378/com.example.android E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no     such table: eventlist
 03-16 20:00:19.122    8378-8378/com.example.android E/SQLiteDatabase﹕    Error inserting college=acs university eventdate=2-02-15 eventname=techocontest
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: eventlist (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO eventlist(college,eventdate,eventname) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Comment: your `insert_data()` database code should be in a transaction, and committed if you like the return code. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Comment: Can you delete your app from your device/emulator and try again? 
*You may have already launched this application with a different database schema definition, your application may have already created a "version 1 database". The `onCreate` is only called if the database doesn't already exist.. The "no such table: eventlist" error message suggests that your onCreate wasn't called.*

Comment: Gorcyn,you are correct! problem solved.Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you are closing the database in the select_data() method.